# Automatically incrementing an index in the following macro generated structs in C++

Tags: c++, templates, macros, template-specialization

I have a template function which looks something like this:

```
template <class T> void foo(T* t)
{
    //do stuff using:
    someArray[idx]; //idx depends on T
}
```

There are a handful of possible types `T`, so my approach was to do something like this in an unnamed namespace:

```
struct Sentinel;
template <class T> struct Offsets {};
#define GENIDX(T,NUM) template <> struct Offsets<T> {static const int idx = NUM;};

GENIDX(Fox, 0)
GENIDX(Cat, 1)
GENIDX(Rat, 2)

GENIDX(Sentinel, 3)

static const size_t numTypes = Offsets<Sentinel>::idx;
```

and then later on, the member array `someArray` is declared with `someArray[numTypes];`

and the foo method is implemented something like this:

```
template <class T> void foo(T* t)
{
    typedef Offsets<T> offset_t;
    someArray[offset_t::idx]; //idx depends on T
}
```

and if someone needs to add a new type to the system, they can just add a new `GENIDX` and everything will work. The only nuisance is that if someone wants to add, say, `Wolf` to the mix, but they want it to logically appear before `Cat` they have to bump the remaining indices manually. I was wondering if there was a way to not require the numerical indices in the macro, and instead let those be automatically sequentially generated. Something like this, except the below doesn't work:

```
size_t numTypes = 0;
template <class T> struct Offsets {};
#define GENIDX(T) template <> struct Offsets<T> {static const int idx = numTypes++;};

GENIDX(Fox)
GENIDX(Cat)
GENIDX(Rat)
```

after which `numTypes` would correctly contain the size of the array. This would not require any index management when inserting new specializations anywhere in the mix and it would be interesting, if at least from a curiosity point of view, to know how this could be done.

Also Though of doing this, after I realized I don't have `__COUNTER__` on my gcc version:

```
template <class T> struct Offsets {};
#define GENIDX(T) \
    template <> struct Offsets<T> \
    { \
      #include BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER() \
      static const int idx = COUNTER; \
    };
```

but the above fails because I can't say `#include` inside the macro...

Comment: Perhaps you meant `typedef Offsets<T> offset_t;`?

Comment: Can you/we use C++11 variadic templates?

Comment: @DyP, I don't have C++11, but I'd be curious to see a solution using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A C++11 solution

Some includes and a helper:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template < typename T0, typename T1 >
constexpr auto c_min(T0 p0, T1 p1)
-> typename std::common_type<T0, T1>::type
{
    return p0 < p1 ? p0 : p1;
}
```

Your types and a "collection" of those types:

```
struct Fox {};
struct Cat {};
struct Rat {};

using my_types = std::tuple < Fox, Cat, Rat >;
```

Two functions:

```
// returns the size of the collection
constexpr std::size_t get_size()
{
    return std::tuple_size<my_types>::value;
}


// `get_index < type > ();` returns the index of a type in that collection

// no definition required, only used to suppress error messages
template < typename, std::size_t >
constexpr std::size_t get_index(std::integral_constant<bool, true>);

template < typename T, std::size_t t = 0 >
constexpr std::size_t get_index(std::integral_constant<bool, false> = {})
{
    using Current = typename std::tuple_element<t, my_types>::type;
    using IsSame = std::is_same<T, Current>;

    static_assert(IsSame{} || t+1 < get_size(),
                  "Unknown type: Passed type not in tuple.");

    using IsError = std::integral_constant< bool,
                                            (IsSame{} || t+1 == get_size()) >;

    return IsSame{} ? t : get_index<T, t+1>( IsError{} );
}
```

Usage example:

```
int someArray[ get_size() ] = {0};


template < class T >
void foo(T* t)
{
    someArray[ get_index<T>() ] = 42;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Array before modification: ";
    for(auto const& e : someArray)
    {
        std::cout << e << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    struct Cow {};
    Cow f;
    foo(&f);

    std::cout << "Array after modification: ";
    for(auto const& e : someArray)
    {
        std::cout << e << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Wow, pretty sophisticated - wish I could patch it in C++98 without having to waithout __COUNTER__ oh well

Comment: @PalaceChan I think you could do most of that in C++98 with more effort. E.g. variadic templates -> multiple templates with different number of parameters (e.g. `boost::tuple`). `constexpr` functions -> metaprogramming.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use `__COUNTER__` ([**`gcc`**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) and [**`VC`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) only I think). It exapands to a sequence of integral values starting from 0 incrementing every time you use it.

```
template <class T> struct Offsets {};
#define GENIDX(T) template <> struct Offsets<T> {static const int idx = __COUNTER__;};
```

Comment: Interesting, where is it defined? I am compiling with gcc (ancient..4.1.2) and I get error: '__COUNTER__' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Ugh Oh..seems like it's gcc 4.3+ for that macro...wonder if I can replicate the macro

Comment: I don't think it has a definition. at least VS doesn't provide one. It needs to be a built-in feature I think.

Comment: @Named It's a predefined macro, and not standardized. [clang also supports it](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html).

Comment: @DyP I don't think it is a normal macro (as in it is a simple text substitution or expansion). It seems a bit complicated and needs actual compiler specific support. Here is parts of how it operates. https://github.com/svp-dev/gcc/blob/master/src/libcpp/pch.c

Comment: @Named It's a pre-defined macro in the same sense that `__LINE__` is a pre-defined macro. The latter one is in the C++ Standard, 16.8/[cpp.predefined]/1